# MySQL query to see changes during the month of last 3 month

Tags: mysql

I want to see changes during the month of last 3 month.

Database:

[image: DATABASE]

MySQL:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CUR.time, '%Y %b') AS thisTime,
   MAX(CUR.value) AS thisValue,
   MAX(PRE.value) AS prevValue,
   MAX(CUR.value)-MAX(PRE.value) AS compValue
FROM test CUR
INNER JOIN test PRE
ON MONTH(PRE.time) = (SELECT MAX(MONTH(XXX.time))
                      FROM test XXX
                      WHERE MONTH(XXX.time) < MONTH(CUR.time))
WHERE CUR.time > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
GROUP BY MONTH(CUR.time)
ORDER BY CUR.id
```

Result:

[image: RESULT]

Can see that there is no January!

I want to see changes during the month of last 3 month like this.
Anyone got ideas?

```
| 2019 Feb | 50 | 40 | 10 |
| 2019 Jan | 40 | 25 | 15 |
| 2018 Dec | 25 | 20 | 5  |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with trying to use `MONTH` in a `JOIN` condition is the wrap around from 12 to 1 at the end of a year. It's easiest just to use the date as a `YEARMONTH` string:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(t1.time, '%b %Y') AS thisTime,
       MAX(t1.value) AS thisValue,
       MAX(t2.value) AS prevValue,
       MAX(t1.value) - MAX(t2.value) AS compValue
FROM test t1
JOIN test t2 ON DATE_FORMAT(t2.time, '%Y%m') = (SELECT MAX(DATE_FORMAT(`time`, '%Y%m')) 
                                                FROM test t3 
                                                WHERE DATE_FORMAT(t3.time, '%Y%m') < DATE_FORMAT(t1.time, '%Y%m'))
GROUP BY thisTime
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('1 ', thisTime), '%d %b %Y') DESC
```

Output:

```
thisTime    thisValue   prevValue   compValue
Feb 2019    50          40          10
Jan 2019    40          25          15
Dec 2018    25          20          5
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=49039246d2485bee76ece7b4d5185b22)

Comment: @JamesKmutnb I've updated my answer. Please in future try to give all the information that is needed to solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much and sorry for my mistakes.

Comment: Can reasonably perform queries on billions of rows?

Comment: @JamesKmutnb with the appropriate indexes, yes. You might also want to consider a generated column which is `DATE_FORMAT(`time`, '%Y%m')` and putting an index on that too.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying a complicated join, you can just use sub-queries since the table isn't very complicated. Also just filter for the results on the 2nd of every month since you don't need the 1st from what your expected result shows.

```
SELECT
  DATE_FORMAT(cur.time,'%Y %b') AS thisTime,
  cur.value AS thisValue,
  (SELECT value FROM test WHERE time = DATE_SUB(cur.time,INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) AS prevValue,
  (SELECT cur.value - value FROM test WHERE time = DATE_SUB(cur.time,INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) AS compValue
FROM
  test AS cur
WHERE
  cur.time >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
AND DATE_FORMAT(cur.time,'%d') = 2
```

Result:

```
thisTime    thisValue   prevValue    compValue
2019 Feb    50          40           10
2019 Jan    40          25           15
2018 Dec    25          20           5
```

***EDIT***
Per Nick's point below, I did assume that the max would always be the 2nd of every month. If that's false and the table snapshot just doesn't happen to show a month where the 1st was the max, then this modification will give the correct max result.

The `JOIN` of `monthMax` and the regular `test` table will guarantee you always pull the max value per month, no matter how many dates there are within that month. Then just use a similar sub-query method as my initial query.

```
SELECT
  DATE_FORMAT(t.time,'%Y %b') AS thisTime,
  t.value AS thisValue,
  (SELECT MAX(value) FROM test WHERE DATE_FORMAT(time,'%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(t.time,INTERVAL 1 MONTH),'%Y-%m')) AS prevValue,
  (SELECT t.value - MAX(value) FROM test WHERE DATE_FORMAT(time,'%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(t.time,INTERVAL 1 MONTH),'%Y-%m')) AS compValue
FROM
  (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(time,'%Y-%m') AS 'timeFix', MAX(value) AS 'maxValue' FROM test GROUP BY timeFix) AS monthMax
JOIN (test AS t) ON (monthMax.maxValue = t.value AND monthMax.timeFix = DATE_FORMAT(t.time,'%Y-%m'))
WHERE
  t.time > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
```

Result:

```
thisTime    thisValue   prevValue    compValue
2019 Feb    50          40           10
2019 Jan    40          25           15
2018 Dec    25          20           5
```

Comment: This query doesn't select the maximum values for each month to compare against.

Comment: That's correct, but I'm assuming from his table structure maybe he only wanted max because he wasn't sure how to approach the question? On the assumption that the 2nd of every month is the max of every month this should always be fine.

Comment: You do have a point although he wasn't specific. Updated my response.

Comment: Suddenly my "complicated join" doesn't look so complicated :-)